# AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient async methods failing with no error

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to use the *AWS CloudWatch* library for logging.
Everything works fine with synchronous methods. However, when I try to use the **async** versions of the same methods, the code fails abruptly, with no exceptions thrown. This piece of line fails:

```
await _amazonCloudWatchLogsClient.PutLogEventsAsync(request);
```

While this line works fine:

```
_amazonCloudWatchLogsClient.PutLogEvents(request);
```

Interestingly, this line works as well:

```
var result = _amazonCloudWatchLogsClient.PutLogEventsAsync(request).Result;
```

At this point I can't think of a way other than going back to the synchronous methods. Again, this is true for **all** the async methods that I've tried, not for this particular method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you have to be careful while calling async methods. One problem in the calling chain will cause issues. In my case, 3 functions up the stack, a method was async with a return value of void.

```
public async void LogBatchThroughput
```

and I was calling this method like a regular method from a synchronous method. This was causing the last async method to be called (PutLogEventsAsync) to fail, silently.
I changed the previous method signature to be:

```
public async Task LogBatchThroughput
```

and called it by .GetAwaiter().GetResult(), from a synchronous method.

This solved the issue. The issue didn't have anything to do with the AWS Cloudwatch libraries.